# Adding command line modifications to the interpreter setup in Aptana Studio on Mac

Tags: python, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio with PyDev for my Python development.

When running my python scripts on my Mac, I want to add:

```
arch -i386
```

on the front of the python command line so I get:

```
arch -i386 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Aptana doesn't seem to let me do this though when setting up a new interpreter.
I've also tried:

```
/usr/bin/arch -i386 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Does anyone kow how I might do this?

!m!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem, the solution seemed easy.

In Aptana, go to the interpreter settings page, there will be a button there to add a new interpreter, do that. Select the alias for the 32 bit python there, ie;

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-32

Then use that intepreter instead of the default one, that works for me.